# Where can I find a working example of socket.io 1.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Where can I find a working example of socket.io 1.0  in combination with express 3.0? Currently the problem is it cannot find  `/socket.io/socket.io.js` in my index.html.

```
var express = require('express')
var http = require('http')
var app = express()

app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80);
});


// setup express server
var serv = http.Server(app);

// setup socket io 
var io = require('socket.io')(serv);
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

serv.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

This is what I have in my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Socket Example</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('/');
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <b>Socket IO</b>
</body>
```

This is what I have in package.json

```
{
  "name": "socketio",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
      "express": "3.0",
      "socket.io": "LearnBoost/socket.io"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: on your console f12 are you getting any 404 for missing files ? Also dont use absolute path try relative path ie /socket.io/socketio.js

Comment: I tried both absolute and relative paths. Same problem is there (404).

Comment: Ok then the file is not there.. 404 means there is no physical file there, are you running a webservice or node ? Is it port 80 ? by default the http:// port is 80 unless you specify it otherwise.

Comment: Am running node on port 80. I have everything working with my previous socket.io version.

Comment: So double check the file structure.. its 404 meaning no file. Not 500 which would be a server error.

Comment: Well, I don't maintain the socket.io.js file. It is automatically served by socket.io in previous versions at least. Not sure about the latest version.

Comment: this is latest version.. i have a suspicion ! You need to wrap express in Node! ill answer now with code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that you decided to you and unfinished, incompleted version of socket.io 1.0. It's not officially released yet (or it would have been in npm). I suggest you stick to the "stable" release of Socket.IO.

If you wanted to use the Socket.IO 1.0 because of the new engine.io transport system I suggest you look at Primus https://github.com/primus/primus which wraps socket.io, engine.io, sockjs and more with a common interface and a plugin system. You can use this plugin system to easily build your own Socket.IO 1.0 by using the engine.io transformer and some plugins. Here's an example https://gist.github.com/3rd-Eden/6113494 of using Primus + Engine.IO to create a **working** clone of Socket.IO

Comment: Thanks 3rdEden, how would I access the socket.io.js/primus on frontend. I mean where would be the location to the socket.io/primus browser side script.

Comment: The location would be /primus/primus.js : `<script src="/primus/primus.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

**You need to wrap the connect/express app in a node http.Server.**

The app.listen() method is a convenience method for this and returns the server:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var app = connect();
var server = app.listen(80);
io.listen(server);
```

**or the following is equivalent:**

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var http = require('http');
var app = connect();
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(80);
io.listen(server);
```

Connect 2 / Express 3 it's possible to create an app without starting an http.server so you should organise it to start or emit. This should get you back on track, if not there are other options.

```
// where this = express();
this.server = this.listen(this.config.port);
console.log('[ ' + this.constants.name + ' ] worker listening on port ' + this.config.port);
this.emit('listen', this.server);
```

For express 3 with server.io and Node : [REF](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: `var serv = http.Server(app);` in my code precisely does what you are saying. Wraps express app in a node server or gives express app as a request handler to node http server. I am using the code directly from documentation given at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io

Comment: ok and when you run your express server are you getting the console message ?!?

Comment: `Express server listening on port 80` is the message

Comment: Im doing a poc of yours but it looks like you have a mix up of sending the server to socket.io and not the express application function. It is supposed to be : "You need to pass the Server to socket.io, and not the express application function."

Comment: Have you tried changing your socket.io dependency ? Just out of intrest!

Comment: This is what is given there in socket.io 1.0 docs 
`var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);` 
and that is exactly what I am doing. Am I wrong?

Comment: var server = require('http').createServer(app);

Please try this.

Comment: Tried that as well. No luck. Thanks a lot for responding.

Comment: I'm really stumped ! Its working on my side! If you find the problem PLEASE let me know! :)

Comment: +1 for the tip about wrapping the Express app in the node http server. This worked for me for Faye: https://github.com/faye/faye/issues/256

Answer (score 0):

You can check this repository which have full socket.io v1.0 implementation. It is with express v4.0 though.

https://github.com/theoctal/livenote